# Add custom CSS to ExtJS App

Tags: css, extjs

I've been trying to add a custom CSS file to the final build from Sencha CMD on ExtJS Application. The application has been generated using the CMD.

My CSS file is located in resources/Custom/myfile.css

try to do many different approach that i found but with no success.

My app.json looks like

```
{
  "builds": {
    "production": {
      "default": true,
      "compressor": {
        "type": "closure"
      }

    }
  },
  "name": "Test.App",
  "css": [
    {
      "path": "resources/Custom/_body.css",
      "remote":  true
    }
  ],
  "requires": [
  ],

  "id": "fb0cc613-c7e3-4e2e-9f9f-aa569fcf2465"
}
```

But when try to build i got the error:

```
BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Combining x-compile in HTML page with Microloader in app.json is not supported
```

If i remove the CSS part fo the app.json it does work !!!

I am using ExtJS 4.1.1

Any Help?

Comment: Hi Varois,
Are able to load mentioned .css file from index.html and check whether reflection of that .css file is on UI or not ?

Comment: Hi there. You i did it. Works when i am using Sencha app watch. But don't work if try to publish the build result on server. All CSS files get 404.

Comment: Its probably the "remote" clause, if you mark the file as true, it will not be copied to deploy.  Remove that and give it a try.

Comment: Hello, tried it as well but with no success. Manage to solve this editing sencha.cfg in .sencha > app. Add the resource folder to app.resource.paths:
    app.resource.paths=${app.dir}/resources